# Как запретить ввод букв в TextBox Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Как запретить ввод букв в TextBox Wpf& вот сам TextBox

```
<TextBox x:Name="MainTextBox" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="330,0,0,96" TextAlignment="Left"/>
```

в интернете есть только для WinForms а если и для WPF то там непонятно взятые KeyPress или типо того.

Comment: Привязать его к числовому формату...?

Comment: а как это сделать...?

Comment: Вы наверно [прикалываетесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562490#comment2814386_1562490), да? Мне под каждым вопросом писать одно и тоже?

Comment: а как это относится к запрету на ввод букв?

Comment: Когда вы привязываете тип с конкретными критериями, в него автоматически идет конвертация, и если это невозможно, текстовое поле подсветится и выдаст предупреждение, которое вы можете отобразить, этого обычно достаточно в 90% случаев, ибо если вы вообще запретите ввод, то это может доставить неудобство пользователю, ибо кто сказал что в это поле вводятся только цифры, м? Ну а если всеж прям хочется, то выбирайте один из [этих](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1268552/6808809) вариантов (яб выбрал с `Behavior`).

Comment: а насчет this, как его сделать отдельным классом или присвоить какое то свойство. просто я в c# недавно

Comment: `public SomeClass { public int Value {get; set} }` ... `private SomeClass _someClass = new(); public MainWindows() { DataContext = _someClass; }` ... `<TextBox Text = "{Binding Value}"/>`. При вводе в текстовое поле что либо, значение будет в `_someClass.Value`, которое вы уже можете получить через код. Ну а при вводе в поле не числа, поле будет красным. И да, начните думать.... Постоянно так вам писать один и тот-же код, ну такое...

Comment: спасибо большое, я вас понял, просто сейчас только вхожу в ООП и после процедурных языков это довольно непросто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчик события `PreviewKeyDown` умеет отменять ввод символов.

```xml
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="textBox_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

```cs
private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9) && e.Key != Key.Back)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Стоит учесть, что этот способ не запретит вставлять неподходящие символы из буфера обмена. Возможно понадобится дополнительный контроль содержимого текстбокса через обработчик `TextChanged`.

Comment: спасибо большое